# FilenameFilter to show list files with certain extension and directories

Tags: java

I am using FilenameFilter class to list all files with certain extension in the directory. But I would also like to list all the directories in that directory.
I searched through the internet and found out only how to use FilenameFilter for multiple extensions. But how can I do that also with directories?

Here is code that I use to list all .txt files:

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
        }
    });
```

Is there even a way to do it via filter or do I have to do it in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many ways of doing this. In particular, a `java.io.FileFilter` gives you more flexibility than a `FilenameFilter`, allowing you to test for directories using `isDirectory()` :

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt") 
                    || pathname.isDirectory();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code

```
 for(File f : Folder.listFiles()){
           String fileName = f.getName();
           String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(".") + 1, f.getName().length());
           fileExtension = fileExtension.toLowerCase();
           if(fileExtension.equals("png") || fileExtension.equals("jpg")){
              System.out.println(f.getName());
           }
       }
```

You can change png or jpg or add something to them

Comment: This will break if you have multiple dots in a filename. Plus you are not answering the directory part of the question.

Comment: I think this will not break fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, f.getName().length()

Comment: That should be fine. You can even omit the second argument to `substring` because the end of string is implied (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int) ).